# Мониторинг ошибок pyQT

Tags: python, pyqt5

Пишу приложение с использованием pyQT.
Не знаю, толи у версии 5.5 такая проблема или это для нее типично.
Но вот падает приложение со значением 1 и шут ее разберет, что за ошибка была. Одно знаю, это точно связано именно с pyQT (локализовывал место остановки, и не раз). Рано или поздно причину ошибки нахожу, но в слепую тыкмыкатся заколебало.

**Есть ли способ получать информацию о такой ошибке?**

Comment: я так понимаю, исходников также никаких нет?

Comment: А смысл? Суть не в конкретной ошибке. Я это замечал не раз и в разных ситуациях.

Comment: Я могу придумать десяток ситуаций, как программа "может падать со значением 1". И в каждом случае будет разлиное описание причин. А может это будет и не падение даже.

Comment: Так суть вопроса не в ошибке!!! Есть ли возможность их отобразить то?!  В поток вывода направить.

Comment: Ещё раз повторяю - как Вы видите, что "программа упала со значением 1" ? Она это вывела в консоль или распечатала на принтере? или человеческим голосом сказала "я упала"!

Comment: "Process finished with exit code 1" в терминале среды разработке...

Comment: Если Вы запускаете приложение самостоятельно и оно возвратит код 1 (а это личное дело приложения, почему оно возвратило такой код), то есть переменная `$?` которая его хранит. [почитать](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/bash_scripting_guide/c3270.html#INTERNALVARIABLES)

Comment: Ну игнорируешь чат и ок, сам отмазывайся от админов. Ближе к сути, эта переменная актуальна при запуске обособленного приложения внутри скрипта или при использовании самого фреймворка? Если второе то попрошу поподробнее.

Comment: эта переменная - часть консоли (баша). И если приложение уже завершилось, то изнутри приложения об этом не узнать. Никак - его уже нет.

Comment: Нет, это не мой случай. Я говорю про сам фреймворк и работу с ним. Да и если и реализовать такой перехват, удобным это не назвать.

Comment: Может все таки приведете код или попробуете запустить простой пример состоящий из одного виджета. Так чтобы возвращаемый результат был 1, и другие люди могли запустить этот код у себя и посмотреть, что не так.

Comment: 1) Код физически находится на изолированной машине, переписывать его руками да еще думать что показать не вижу смысла т.к. => 2) ВОПРОС НЕ ПРО ОШИБКУ, бляха муха! Нет ее! считайте что она гипотетическая! Она была не одна, их было предостаточно и все разные. И вопрос вовсе не про ошибку а как точно перехватит информацию о краше QT.

Comment: И что это за место остановки?

Comment: Я вот принципиально не буду уточнять, если понять не хотим. Меня интересует перехват данных о ошибке произошедшей где-то на стороне QT. Я заколебался не конкретно с этой ошибкой, я заколебался в слепую выяснять причину. Если нет такого способа - напиши ответ с отрицанием, есть раскажи о перехвате. Третьего не дано.

Answer (score 1):

Очень странно что у вас крашится в QT. Так в большинстве случаев либо происходит Exception, из которого легко понять в чем проблема. Либо QT падает в Segmentation fault.

Дальше как вам и написал KoVadim возвращаемый код дело разработчика. Он мог решить в некоторых ситуациях возвращать код отличный от нуля.

Также код отличный от нуля может возвращаться из-за среды разработки, например в PyCharm была ошибка и при дебаге возвращался код 135. И тогда уже нужно смотреть документацию и/или багтрекер IDE.

Возвращаемый код из QT определяется двумя методами, если в приложении вызван quit(по умолчанию) то будет 0, или вызван метод exit(код возврата), то соответственно будет код возврата тот, который передан в функцию.

Вот простой пример, просто закрываете - все хорошо, нажимаете кнопку и будет код возврата 5. Код 5 просто потому что это я так решил.

```
from PyQt5 import Qt

class Window(Qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.btn = Qt.QPushButton()
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.on_button)

    def on_button(self):
        Qt.QApplication.instance().exit(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    result = app.exec()
    print(result)
    if result == 0:
        print("It's OK!")
    else:
        print("Something wrong! Button was pressed!")
```